# Flow DIVs so that they use free space instead of just stacking

Tags: html, css

I got four divs.

Div two is half the height of div 1, div 3 & 4 is half the height of div 2.

On a large display the placement of the divs are fine:

```
---------------- ---------- -------- --------
|              | |  Div 2 | | Div 3| | Div 4 |
|    Div 1     | |________|  -------  -------
|              | 
|              |
----------------
```

On smaller screens I want the following layout:

```
---------------- ----------
|              | |  Div 2 |
|    Div 1     | |________|
|              | |  Div 3 |
|              | ----------
---------------- | Div 4  |
```

i.e. div 3 and 4 are placed under div 2.

But instead they are placed under div 1:

```
---------------- ----------
|              | |  Div 2 |
|    Div 1     | |________|
|              | 
|              |
----------------
-------- --------
| Div 3| | Div 4 |
 -------  -------
```

Is it possible to get the second alternative in some way? In my own attempts I have never got both the large screen and the smaller screen alternatives to  work with the same code.

Comment: Have you tried something like: `@media screen and (max-width: ?px) { Div 2, Div 3, Div 4 { display: block; }}` ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Div1 placement gets a bit wierd: https://jsfiddle.net/w31jv3un/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use the CSS property `flexbox` ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)) to achieve this. See the example below (in full screen and stretch your screen).

While starting *mobile first*, you can work your way up and with setting [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries), you can easily modify the visual hierarchy of the boxes. First, put a `display: flex;` on the wrapper `div` and then on the desired breakpoint (here `480px`), add another `display: flex;` on the `.inner-wrapper`.

Note: this is just a quick setup and there are many ways to do this.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
}

.box-large {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}

.box-small {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.5%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .inner-wrapper {
    display: flex;
  }
}

/* Visual stuff */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box-one {
  background-color: red;
}

.box-two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.box-three {
  background-color: green;
}

.box-four {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-one box-large">red</div>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="box-two box">blue</div>
    <div class="box-three box-small">green</div>
    <div class="box-four box-small">yellow</div>
  </div>

</div>
```